# C lib to open sqllite db?

Tags: sql, c

Is there anyway to open an sqlite database in c without having to have the sqlite exes and dlls.
Is there a lib to do this.
I only want to read the database, not write.

Comment: Are you really saying you want to use a sqlite database without the sqlite library ? If it's that the answer is you can provided you write your own copying relevant parts from official sqlite library. But IMHO you *do not want* that

Comment: `sqlite.c` is one-file embeddable library. It is only sane way to do so. Nothing could be better.

Comment: Why don't you want to just use sqlite library?

Comment: **Note:** the `sqlite.c` and `sqlite3` interfaces are two distinct and different tools (basically `sqlite` version different). Make sure you choose the correct tool for the job. If it didn't sink in from the first comment: **It would be insane to attempt to reinvent either interface...** Just use the one you need, they are excellent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the [SQLite3 C/C++ interface](https://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html)?

(See the second bulletpoint of the section titled "Write Programs that use SQLite" at the bottom of [this page](https://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html) for a quick example on how to use it.)